# PhpStorm. Collecting files very slow

Tags: phpstorm

I use "Deployment" feature in my PHPStorm and this on executes "Collecting files"  first. But in takes a while around 30 min.

What's "Collection files" is  and is it nessesary for deployment and is it possible to disable it?

Comment: Do you have a very high number of small files? That could slow down the whole process of checking files. By the way..are you using `passive mode` , for the ftp connection? I used to see some speed improvements when ticking that checkbox in `Advanced options` for the FTP connection :)

Comment: Try rsync. The deployment feature is a joke when it comes to speed (files per second).  Apparently it takes 8 years to implement effective uploads (see lena's answer). The link speed between here and the node is 118 Mbits/sec, measured with iperf3!

Answer (score 5):

It scans files and folders on server, collecting information about them. This indeed may take a while, especially in case of slow network connection. There is unfortunately no way to skip this step. Please vote for  [WI-3268](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3268)

Comment: How does one vote for WI-3268? I am a paying customer / logged in user. .... NVM got it. there is "like button"

Answer (score -2):

Collection is slow for you because the IDE config not optimal not because of PhpStorm itself. Make sure PhpStorm is using the most current jre, jdk if u want to use PhpStorm64. Make sure ur java_home is properly set as well. Optimizing the underlying java config will speed everything up dramatically. In addition, utilize the exclude directory feature and minimize unnecessary plugins.